# Name based virtual hosts with SSL on Apache 2.2.3/CentOS 5.9

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

Hi I'm trying to serve one site with two subdomains, and both subdomains should be under SSL. I've purchased a wildcard SSL certificate and have it installed. In my vhosts file I have 5 definitions, www (80), app (80/443), and staging (80/443). All of the subdomains work under port 80.

Here's a snippet of my vhosts.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin support@---
  ServerName app.---
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/---/app/www/
  ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/---/app/log/error.log

  <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/---/app/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin support@---
  ServerName app.---
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/---/app/www/
  ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/---/app/log/ssl.log

  SSLEngine ON
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl/---/ssl.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl/---/ssl.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl/---/intermediate.crt

  <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/---/app/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin support@---
  ServerName staging.---
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/---/staging/www/
  ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/---/staging/log/error.log

  <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/---/staging/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin support@---
  ServerName staging.---
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/---/staging/www/
  ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/---/staging/log/ssl.log

  SSLEngine ON
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl/---/ssl.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl/---/ssl.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl/---/intermediate.crt

  <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/---/staging/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I change this line:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

To:

```
<VirtualHost SERVER_IPADDRESS:443>
```

The first definition will work as expected and use the correct certificate. When I restart Apache I receive a message in the terminal stating there's a duplicate entry and only the first will be used.

With the conf as it is above I don't receive any errors or warnings in the terminal, but I have seen this in Apache's log:

```
[warn] Init: You should not use name-based virtual hosts in conjunction with SSL!!
```

From what I've read online that warning is expected and shouldn't be a problem.

Running configtest shows Syntax OK.

It seems the problem is named virtual hosts with SSL. I've checked 3 guides online and tried a variety of things (using *.domain.com as ServerName for both, app.domain.com as ServerAlias), subdomains as the directive (app.domain.com:443) but can't figure out the right combination to serve each subdomain under both 80 and 443 using only one IP address.

I know it's possible. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I was able to find which isn't a great one was to rebuild on CentOS 6.4. The issue as noted by Russ is that the built in Apache/OpenSSL do not support SNI. I managed to get OpenSSL upgraded in 5.9, but I was not able to build Apache with SNI. I compiled it using a guide that showed the flags to use but it didn't work. That's not to say it can't be done and I may have done it wrong, this was easier since it's for a new site and downtime isn't an issue.

Once the issue was corrected the warning in error_log changes to this:

```
[warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of apache you are using.  It may be that your apache is too old to support it.  I think sni was supported in apache 2.2.12 and later.

Comment: Updated my post, httpd -v shows Apache/2.2.23 (Unix). Is SNI included by default or do I have to install it on my own?

Comment: Not sure about centos 5.9.  The only time I have used SNI I compiled my own apache from the new 2.4 version.  It also required a minimum version of openssl to work as well so that may be another thing to check.

Comment: You don't need SNI to be working if you only have one wildcard cert. SNI is used to select the correct cert to return to the client if you have 2 or more certs.

Comment: Thats a good point. :)  The message just triggered SNI in my brain and I did not think about having only the one cert to present.

Comment: @wollybrain I'm about to rebuild on CentOS6 since I can't install newer versions of OpenSSL/Apache on 5.9. Any suggestions before I do?

Comment: Like woollybrain said.  If you only have the one ssl cert then it won't matter whether sni works.  it only matters if you want to have more than 1 cert per ip address.

Comment: That's what I was asking- it's not working, so if SNI isn't required what is the problem?

Comment: did you also change the NameVirtualHost *:443 line to match the <VirtualHost SERVER_IPADDRESS:443> section?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The top has always been *:443 and I've tried both for the VirtualHost directive.

Comment: The * means all interfaces.  So if you want it to listen on all IP addresses that is what you want.  If you are going to have multiple ssl sites you need to put each one on a different IP address(or use sni).  So you just need to change the NameVirtualHost *:443 to NameVirtualHost SERVER_IPADDRESS:443 so that it matches the <VirtualHost SERVER_IPADDRESS:443>.

Comment: I can't do that since I have two subdomains that both need the certificate. I'd end up with two entries with the same IP directive and Apache only serves the first.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42807/discussion-between-russ-huguley-and-jonathan)

Comment: I appreciate the help but I ended up rebuilding. CentOS 5.9 has too many outdated packages to try to get it working.

Comment: yes 5.9 is pretty old.  If you are still have the same problem let me know.